# Bot not responding when automoderation is disabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js

On my Discord bot, users are able to choose for a discord invite detection automod if they want the bot to delete the message, kick the user, ban the user, or softban the user with all of this being stored on MongoDB. But when a user disables automod on their guild, it stops responding to all commands until it is turned back on manually by editing MongoDB files

here is my message.js code:

https://haste.pancake.gg/ludiritaga.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a relatively simple mistake, believe it or not. I've made this mistake many times before, so you aren't alone!
Your command detection statement is enclosed within the if(linkDetect === `on`) {...} statement.

```
        )}}}} //Add a closing bracket here. This will exclude the portion of code that operates command detection from the else-if statement that checks if invite detection is on, allowing commands to be used while the feature is disabled.
        



    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

    const command =
        client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) ||
        client.commands.find(
            (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())
        );
    if (!command) return;
        try {
    command.execute(message, args, client);
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            const errorEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RED')
                .setDescription('**<:xmark:763662710130737152> There was an error, please report it in my [support server](https://discord.gg/q4dunRn).**\n\n' + `\`${err}\``)
            message.channel.send(errorEmbed)
        }
    } //Remove this bracket, as it is unnecessary once you add an additional closing bracket as suggested above. This bracket originally closed the else-if statement that only ran when invite detection was enabled
}
```

Also, to avoid this in the future (if you don't already do this), you can use an IDE that allows you to see where both of a code block's brackets are, so you can troubleshoot this kind of issue easier in the future.

Hope I could help!